# Changing background color

Tags: css, colors, background

I have a problem with my background colors. on some pages i use TinySlider, and it sets the background color to grey. And when i try to change it to for example Orange, it will only change on those pages that does not use Tiny Slider. Is there a way to fix this?

I have uploaded the files to google drive. [The link for all files](https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0BxsqMLXovlRHVTdfWkNSRUZCUzA/edit)

The style.css is for the TinySlider, while the stilark.css is the one that is used for all the pages.
the index.html uses TinySlider, while skolen.html does not.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the

```
body {font:12px Verdana,Arial; color:#555; background:#ddd}
```

of "style.css" into

```
body {font:12px Verdana,Arial; color:#555; background-color:#FEAD41}
```

Comment: Thank you! i've tried it before without any luck, but suddenly it works :D Thank you so much! You might have saved my work :D